# Is it possible to forge a SafetyNet Attestation token/x509 certificate

Tags: android, x509certificate, x509, safetynet, safetynet-api

I was instructed to implement the [API SafetyNet Attestation](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) in an app and there were some concerns about verifying the token.

We created an endpoint that will return a nonce generated on the server side that will include the hash of a mix of information to be validated later.

We need to implement the token verifier to run on the server side, and it will be basically a copy and paste of `OfflineVerify.java` provided by google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/blob/master/server/java/src/main/java/OfflineVerify.java).

The issue is that I'm not sure whether one can forge this token/x509 certificate. According to the Attestation documentation, we need to check the host name in the certificate that should match *attest.android.com* and we can also validate other info present in the payload as well as the nonce.

I'm not an expert in cryptography/certificates but shouldn't we need to have a private key to validate the certificate?

Wouldn't it be possible to someone to create a x509 certificate, set its hostname to *attest.android.com* and the other fields to be just like the one returned from google and generate a *genuine* token that will pass the `OfflineVerify.java`?

I'd really appreciate any insights on this.

Thanks

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291486/android-safetynet-jwt-signature-verification, basically someone _could_ create a new certificate, but it would not be issued by a trusted certificate authority and so the [`verifySignature`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/f7948014150d0205ffb6abf322e97e0c03b4ee16/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/json/webtoken/JsonWebSignature.java#L434) method would fail.